# Using tikz \foreach inside an \edef

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I would like to use `\foreach` inside an `\edef`, for example to define a set of random points as follows:

```
\edef\mypoints{%
  \foreach \x in {0,.1,...,1}
           {\pgfmathparse{rand} (\x,\pgfmathresult)}}
```

Unfortunately, the above code causes an error about 
`Undefined control sequence \pgffor@remember@once@code`.

My questions are why this doesn't work, and what the simplest workaround is for saving the result of a `\foreach` loop.

Comment: I think we've got a lot questions on the `\foreach` expansion trap

Comment: @ChristianHupfer When I search for "foreach expansion trap," I get no results on stackexchange, so how do I find these?

Comment: Do you really need `\edef`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It's absolutely necessary.  Otherwise, I get new random points each time, which doesn't work very well in, say, overlay slides.

Comment: @user3188445 You can set a seed: `\pgfmathsetseed{1}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I understand, but in my case it's really necessary.  I need to use these points over and over in a bunch of different contexts, and don't want to be resetting the random seed as a side effect of using the macro.  Also, I'm generating a lot of these points, and it's slow to keep doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer provides a solution which works but has the downside of using global definitions, which should be avoided unless really necessary. pgf comes with the `/.list` key handler which allows one to avoid the global definitions.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[add point/.code={\pgfmathparse{rand}%
    \edef\mypoints{\mypoints(#1,\pgfmathresult)}}]
    \def\mypoints{} % initialize
    \tikzset{add point/.list={0,0.2,...,5}}% loop without global definitions
    \draw plot coordinates {\mypoints};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to do the cycle outside the `\edef`:

```
\gdef\mypoints{} % initialize
\foreach\x in {0,0.1,...,1} {%
  \pgfmathparse{rand}%
  \xdef\mypoints{\mypoints(\x,\pgfmathresult)}%
}
```

so at each cycle you append the new point.

---

With the code above we might get something like

```
(0,-0.5593)(0.1,0.51411)(0.20001,0.55302)
(0.30002,0.51347)(0.40002,-0.54858)(0.50003,-0.64978)
(0.60004,0.61548)(0.70004,-0.32903(0.80005,0.2993)
(0.90005,-0.38226)
```

(line breaks for clarity). Well, not really what we expected.

We can avoid this and also global declarations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\fpforeach}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = start, #2 = step, #3 = end, #4 = template
  \fp_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\clearlist}{m}
 {
  \tl_clear_new:c { l_egreg_list_#1_tl }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\tl_put_right:cx}{\tl_put_right:cn} { l_egreg_list_#2_tl } { #3 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\uselist}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { l_egreg_list_#1_tl }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
  
\clearlist{points} % initialize
\fpforeach{0}{0.1}{1}{%
  \addtolist*{points}{(#1,\fpeval{round(2*rand()-1,4)}) }
}

\begin{document}

\raggedright
\uselist{points}

\end{document}
```

Since `rand()` only returns numbers between 0 and 1, but the `pgfmath` function `rand` returns numbers from −1 to 1, I use `2*rand()-1`.

A possible output is

[image]

The trailing space is just for typesetting purposes. In the fourth argument of `\fpforeach`, `#1` stands for the current value in the loop.

The `\addtolist` command simply adds, but with `*` it also does full expansion.

Note that the x-coordinates are indeed from 0 to 1, because `l3fp` uses floating point decimal numbers (not fixed precision binary converted into decimal like `pgfmath`).

Comment: That answers half of my question, thanks.  But can you explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: @user3188445 No assignments are performed in an `\edef`, just macro expansion is done. There are several topics on the site that deal with the problem.

Comment: @user3188445 Try `\edef\mypoints{\pgfmathparse{rand}}`. Not everything is expandable.