# Cannot save value to variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, errors, loops, variable

This code defines a custom printing function that prints the numbers 1 to input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\mynewprint[1] {
    \foreach[parse=true] \i in {1,...,#1} {
        \i
    }
}

\mynewprint{4}

\end{document}
```

Result:

```
1 2 3 4
```

However when I try to save the string of numbers then print it, it no longer works. In the second code I define a custom variable to save the results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\mynewprint[1] {
    \edef\mynewstring {
        \foreach[parse=true] \i in {1,...,#1} {
            \i
        }
    }
    \mynewstring
}

\mynewprint{4}

\end{document}
```

Result(Error):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\foreach ...reach \let \pgffor@assign@before@code =\pgfutil@empty \let \pgff...

l.14 \mynewprint{4}
```

What is wrong in the second code?

Comment: Welcome! There are too many errors in your second code. However, it's unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: You cannot `\edef` a `\foreach`. You need an expandable loop or a different approach with `\xdef` inside a loop. If you just need a sequence of numbers stored in a macro, there are other ways. It would be good to know why you are trying to do that.

Comment: you can't do assignments in an edef, so even without knowing the details of foreach the asignment of the `\i` loop variable could not work

Comment: I'd say the comments above while technically true is not very useful to a "typical" user. I'd just say, **you simply can't "evaluate" a foreach inside a edef**, and there are workarounds (there's an example in [Using tikz \foreach inside an \edef - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271511/using-tikz-foreach-inside-an-edef)) that allows it to work.